# getting the location of a file as string in c++

Tags: c

I'm try to get the location of file let's say :     **D\stuff.tif**  in my program a string like :

```
 filename = 'D:\stuff.tif'
```

I need it in ths form so here what I've been trying:

```
  char text[50];// = "filename = ";
   char filep [50];
   printf("get file name ") ;
   scanf("%s",&filep);
   sprintf(text," filename = \' %s \'",filep);
```

it doesn't work any Idea ? ? 
 thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: it should be `filename = 'D:\\stuff.tif'`; do you want to read this from the console? what doesn't work? what did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` should take a `char *` as an argument; you're giving it a `char (*)[50]` by taking the address of `filep`.  Try:

```
  char text[50];// = "filename = ";
   char filep [50];
   printf("get file name ") ;
   scanf("%s",filep);  // <- removed address-of here
   sprintf(text," filename = \' %s \'",filep);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do realize that what you wrote is C rather than C++? In C++ you would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string text, filep;
    std::cout << "get file name ";
    std::cin >> filep;
    text = " filename = '" + filep + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
char text[255];// = "filename = ";
char filep [50];
printf("get file name ") ;
scanf("%s",filep);
sprintf(text," filename = \'%s\'",filep);
```